# How to integration test the encrypted URL

Tags: java, security, url, encryption, integration-testing

I have a situation when server creates an encrypted URL which is passed to client. Then the client can asses another service (a servlet) via this URL. I'm writing an integration test that must confirm that the URL that client received is **really encrypted**. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to encrypt it in the test exactly the same way you do on the server and then compare results.

Comment: Thanks! After reading your reply I found an answer! I'll try to decrypt the received URL (string) using the same key that will be used on the remote service(where the URL will be decrypted in production)

Answer (score 1):

Test the encryption method for some static strings with known results.

Comment: That would help if is was unit-testing it. I'm writing an integration test that verifies that whole use case: "server creates encrypted URL"->"URL is sent to user"->"User clicks the URL"->"User receives the result from remote service". I need to verify that URL **is encrypted** when "user" (my testing entity) receives the URL